# Memoization By Hand in Python Function Using Tuples as Cache Keys

Tags: python, memoization

I'm trying to implement by-hand memoization in the following function, which calculates the optimal please of eating chocolates given that waiting supposedly increases the pleasure:

```
def joy(chocs, day):
    n = len(chocs)
    if n == 1:
        return day * chocs[0]
    left = day * chocs[0] + joy(chocs[1:], day + 1)
    right = day * chocs[n - 1] + joy(chocs[:n - 1], day + 1)
    return max(left, right)
```

I want to use a `cache` dictionary to store prvious results, but I'm stuck on the implementation. Here's my attempt so far:

```
def joy(chocs, day, cache={}):
    if (chocs, day) in cache:
        return cache[(chocs, day)]
    n = len(chocs)
    if n == 1:
        return day * chocs[0]
    left = day * chocs[0] + joy(chocs[1:], day + 1)
    right = day * chocs[n - 1] + joy(chocs[:n - 1], day + 1)
    return max(left, right)
```

I'm stuck on what to use as the key/value for storing the left/right results.

Can anyone help me to complete the memoized version of the function please?

Comment: You've got the first part right of returning from cache if it is present. But you also need to add logic to insert into the cache before returning (if it isn't in the cache).

Comment: save what you want to return in a variable i.e. `day * chocs[0]` and `max(left, right)`. Then store that in the cache and only then return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the result in your cache before you return.

```py
result = max(left, right)
cache[(chocs, day)] = result
return result
```

There's no need to store the result of the base case.

Answer (score 1):

just invert your logic

```
def joy(chocs, day, cache={}):
    if (chocs, day) not in cache:
        n = len(chocs)
        if n == 1:
            cache[(chocs,day)] = day * chocs[0]
        else:
            left = day * chocs[0] + joy(chocs[1:], day + 1)
            right = day * chocs[n - 1] + joy(chocs[:n - 1], day + 1)
            cache[(chocs,day)] = max(left, right)
    return cache[(chocs, day)]
```

this way your cache is ensured